# Adding Jackson annotation to a swagger generated class

Tags: java, jackson, swagger

I'm using swagger to define a contract with my web server. In the swagger file I define the REST endpoints and the request/response objects.

I would like to add the annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to a field in my swagger class. The swagger class is defined something like this:

```
 MyObject:
    discriminator: valueType
    required:
      - name
      - description
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      description:
        type: string
      value:
        type: string
      dbName:
        type: string
```

When `dbName` is null, I would like to not return it (not serialize it) so I'd get a response that looks like:

```
{
   "name": "some_name",
   "description": "my description",
   "value": "some value"
}
```

If it were a java class I create, it would have been very easy to just define it as:

```
public class MyObject {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String value;

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public String dbName;
}
```

But because that's an auto-generated class, I'm not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: try allowEmptyValue and nullable parameters as described in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ (Under section Empty-Valued and Nullable Parameters)

Comment: @PraveenE - Thanks, but it's not that I want to allow it to be null, because today it already returns this field when it's null. I want this field to not be serialized at all when it's null. As I understand from your link, it's not the case (or am I wrong?).

Comment: @Avi Did you ever find the solution to your question? Thanks

Comment: @howells699 - nope :(

Comment: @Avi Are you using Spring Boot? I have a solution if so. Thanks

Comment: @howells699 , can you share the solution for spring boot?

Comment: Hi @Avi any luck on this since then? I am wanting the same ability to either specify Jackson annotations directly on the generated model classes & its fields or an ability to specify them in the yaml definition...it seems the documentation is just non-existent...i am wondering how one can use swagger with such poor support beyond simple hello world examples :-(

Comment: @howells699 please share your answer if u have a way...it will help us all..

Comment: @matrixguy Did you figure out a way by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using swagger-codegen plugin then in Maven config you need to add the **notNullJacksonAnnotation** CLI option and also check if you're using latest plugin version, e.g.:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.32</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/petstore.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>java</language>
                        <library>resttemplate</library>
                        <apiPackage>lt.codex.json.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>lt.codex.json.model</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>lt.codex.json.handler</invokerPackage>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <notNullJacksonAnnotation>true</notNullJacksonAnnotation>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```