# How to add Jackson annotations to specific fields on swagger generated model classes for Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

Folks,

With swagger 2.0 does anyone know if it's possible to add Jackson annotations to specific fields on swagger generated model classes when using swagger codegen with 'spring' as the 'language' `<language>spring</language>`?

I want to use Jackson JSON Views & would like to add the view annotations to provide different views of the generated models when I return them from the various REST endpoints. However, I could not find any documentation if any on this on swagger.

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517796/adding-jackson-annotation-to-a-swagger-generated-class) slightly similar question both having the same problem, which is either the lack of support or the lack of documentation for this basic functionality.

I am frankly quite surprised **how swagger can be used beyond basic hello world examples with this type of real-world support issue**...

Thanks